# How to use pm2 start npm in a specific directory?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, pm2

Is there a CLI tag for running `pm2 start npm -- start` in a specific directory? I looked around but could not find an answer.

On the other hand, when I run pm2 **without** npm, I can specify which directory I want to run pm2 in. For example:

`pm2 start /opt/www/myapp/index.js`

Is there any way to add a path tag to the `pm2 start npm -- start` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
cd /directory/of/my/app ; pm2 start npm -- start
```

You can also write an ecosystem file to parameter you app:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "my-app",
            "cwd": "/path/to/app",
            "script": "npm",
            "args": "start"
        }
    ]
}
```

To generate an empty ecosystem file:

```
pm2 init simple
```

this will generate a file named `ecosystem.config.js` that you can rename.

Then to start application:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

ecosystem doc: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/